# Understanding range() in a for loop

Tags: python

I was just wandering why this program does not work if I modify my for loop from for i in range(len(string[i]) with for i in string. I get a type error?

```
def lowerChar(char):

     if ord(char) >= ord("A") and ord(char) <= ord("Z"):
         return chr(ord(char)+32)
     else:
         return char

def lowerString(string):
     result = ""
     for i in range(len(string)):
         result = result + lowerChar(string[i])
         return result

print(lowerString('Hey There'))
```

Comment: When you iterate directly over a string, the loop variable is the characters of that string.  Rename the variables accordingly `for character in string:` and that should help make sense of what your program is doing

Comment: Also, there's a syntax error on the `for` definition: you're missing a closing `)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 for i in range(len(string)):
     result = result + lowerChar(string[i])
```

could be rewritten as:

```
 for ch in string:
     result = result + lowerChar(ch)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, it's a simple mistake - you missed a closing bracket. Use this:

`for i in range(len(string))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the brackets around `range()` i.e.

```
for i in range(len(string)):
```

full properly indented code that works when tested:

```
def lowerChar(char):

    if ord(char) >= ord("A") and ord(char) <= ord("Z"):
        return chr(ord(char)+32)
    else:
        return char

def lowerString(string):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        result = result + lowerChar(string[i])
    return result

print(lowerString('Hey There'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in range(N)` means the loop will be executed N times with i taking values from 0 to N-1.